# Whats the difference between ansible 'raw', 'shell' and 'command'?

Tags: ansible

What is the difference between `raw`, `shell` and `command` in the ansible playbook? And when to use which?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[command](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/command_module.html): executes a remote command on the target host, in the same shell of other playbook's tasks.
It can be used for launch scripts (.sh) or for execute simple commands. For example:

```
- name: Cat a file
  command: cat somefile.txt

- name: Execute a script
  command: somescript.sh param1 param2
```

[shell](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/shell_module.html): executes a remote command on the target host, opening a new shell (/bin/sh).
It can be used if you want to execute more complex commands, for example, commands concatenated with pipes. For example:

```
- name: Look for something in a file
  shell: cat somefile.txt | grep something
```

[raw](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/raw_module.html): executes low-level commands where the interpreter is missing on the target host, a common use case is for installing python. This module should not be used in all other cases (where command and shell are suggested)

Answer (score 6):

Since I were I stumbling about the same question, I wanted to share my findings here too.

The `command` and `shell` module, as well `gather_facts` (annot.: `setup.py`) depend on a properly installed Python interpreter on the Remote Node(s). If that requirement isn't fulfilled one may experience errors were it isn't possible to execute

```bash
python <ansiblePython.py>
```

In a Debian 10 (Buster) minimal installation i.e., `python3` was installed but the symlink to `python` missing.

To initialize the system correctly before applying all other roles, I've used an approach with the `raw` module

**ansible/initSrv/main.yml**

```yaml
- hosts: "{{ target_hosts }}"
  gather_facts: no # is necessary because setup.py depends on Python too

  pre_tasks:
  - name: "Make sure remote system is initialized correctly"
    raw: 'ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python'
    register: set_symlink
    failed_when: set_symlink.rc != 0 and set_symlink.rc != 1
```

which is doing something like

```bash
/bin/sh -c 'ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python'
```

on the remote system.

**Further Documentation**

- [`raw` module – Executes a low-down and dirty command](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/raw_module.html)

  > *A common case is installing `python` on a system without python installed by default.*

<sub>*... but not only restricted to that*</sub>

- [Playbook Keyword - `pre_tasks`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/playbooks_keywords.html#task)

  > *A list of tasks to execute before roles.*
- [Set the order of task execution in Ansible](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/ansible-pretasks-posttasks)

**Another Use Case**

- [How to have Ansible figure out where the desired Python is?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54567439/6771046)