# cannot ignore errors with shell command

Tags: ansible

I'm using Python 3.10.1 and I've installed Ansible using PIP version 21.2.4

`ansible --version` returns the following

```
ansible [core 2.12.1]
  config file = /Users/user_name/Projects/support/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/Users/user_name/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /Users/user_name/.pyenv/versions/3.10.1/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ansible
  ansible collection location = /Users/user_name/.ansible/collections:/usr/share/ansible/collections
  executable location = /Users/user_name/.pyenv/versions/3.10.1/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.10.1 (main, Jan  3 2022, 06:39:07) [Clang 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30)]
  jinja version = 3.0.3
  libyaml = True
```

In my playbook, I'm able to run all of the tasks except for any `shell` or `command` module call which has the ignore errors directive.

Here's the offending entry:

```
  - name: RBENV init
    become_user: deploy
    become: true
    command:
      chdir: /home/deploy/
      cmd: rbenv init
      ignore_errors: yes
```

Which returns:

```
FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Unsupported parameters for (ansible.legacy.command) module: ignore_errors. Supported parameters include: warn, strip_empty_ends, _uses_shell, argv, _raw_params, chdir, creates, stdin, removes, executable, stdin_add_newline."}
```

What's interesting is that if I remove `ignore_errors: yes` the command executes but then chokes on the non-zero response `rbenv init` returns.

I'm brand new to Ansible and and when I google that error message I get posts from like 5 and 6 years ago where the user is using an at the time outdated version of Ansible. Am I using the current version? How would I determine this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According the documentation of [Error handling in playbooks](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_error_handling.html) and the error message

> `Unsupported parameters for (ansible.legacy.command) module: ignore_errors. Supported parameters include: warn, strip_empty_ends, _uses_shell, argv, _raw_params, chdir, creates, stdin, removes, executable, stdin_add_newline.`

your indents are incorrect. So the error is just caused by a typo and you may use instead

```
- name: RBENV init
  become_user: deploy
  become: true
  command:
    chdir: /home/deploy/
    cmd: rbenv init
  ignore_errors: yes
```

You may also have a look into [whats the difference between ansible `raw`, `shell` and `command`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57804071/)

Quote: "*It can be used if you want to execute more complex commands, for example commands concatenated with pipes*".

Regarding

> ... but then chokes on the non-zero response `rbenv init` returns.

and in general for your command, you may introduce [`failed_when`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_error_handling.html#defining-failure) instead of ignoring errors at all.

Comment: thanks @U880D that did it. After seeing your response and reading the documentation again I can see that `ignore_errors` is a parameter for the task itself and not just the command module. thank you again.