# Ansible: environment variables not exported when using sudo in shell command

Tags: shell, ansible, environment-variables, ansible-2.x, ansible-template

I am facing issues in exporting environment variables as part of the following Ansible task -

```
- name: Run custom shell script
  shell: "sudo bash custom_script.sh"
  register: output
  environment:
    ENV_VAR1: "secret-key"
```

During execution, the process is not able to find the `ENV_VAR1`.

Another way is to explicitly export the variable in the shell command, something like -

```
- name: Run custom shell script
  shell: "sudo su -c 'export ENV_VAR1=\"secret-key\"; bash custom_script.sh'"
  register: output
```

But, I not comfortable with this approach, and would like to make use of the `environment` functionality provided by Ansible.

***Note:*** Please note, I will not be able to use `become: true` as well, and have to run the shell command through `sudo`.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To tell `sudo` to keep the environment, you can use `--preserve-env` to keep all the variables or `--preserve-env=ENV_VAR1` to keep only the required ones.

P.S. There is [much more](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_privilege_escalation.html) on privilege escalation that just `become: true` so you might find a way to use it. Also, you're using `shell` instead of `command` which could also affect the behavior of your script. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57805603/16417367) answer has more details on that with links to the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather use "become: true" and "become_user: xxx" instead of "sudo" inside the command. Works fine.

```
  - name: Run custom command
    shell: "echo environment env1 $env1 user $USER"
    become: true
    become_user: oracle
    register: output

  - debug:
      msg: '{{ output.stdout }}'

  environment:
   env1: "secret-key"
```

Output:

```
"msg": "environment env1 secret-key user oracle"
```

Sorry, just missed your note you are not able to use "become". May I ask why not?