# Ansible raw gives different results than running a command on the terminal

Tags: ansible

When running the following custom command `/abc/fold/bin/abh 'ansible'` on the terminal of my ansible target, it works fine. I tried to run it from different directories to see if that makes a difference. But it works from all directories I tried it from

When trying to  register the result of the command I however get a different result.

```
- name: Get template
  ansible.builtin.raw: /abc/fold/bin/abh 'ansible'
  register: log_template
```

When printing the output

```
- name: Print template
  ansible.builtin.debug:
    msg: "Log template {{ log_template.stdout }}"
```

I can see that there are import errors.
How can I run the command exactly the same as it would be as running it on the terminal of the machine.

The machines os is windriver linux 6

Comment: "_How can I run the command exactly the same as it would be as running it on the terminal of the machine._", can you show both results and outputs and highlights what's the difference between? "_I can see that there are import error_", in your question are no error messages or output, can you provide them?

Comment: import [redacted]\r\nImportError: No module named [redacted]\r\nbasename:  Where redacted is replaced for security reasons

Comment: Based on your comment stub one can only guess, but you'll probably need to disable fact gathering. See [Whats the difference between ansible `raw`, `shell` and `command`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64817243/6771046)

Comment: @U880D turns out the environment is not the same when running through ansible/directly on the server. solved it by adding environment variables manually for the ansible tasks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After lots of searching, I found out that the environment is different. I tried running echo $PATH through ansible and compare the result with the output when ran directly on the server.
I solved it by manually adding all the environment variables like:

```
- name: Get template
  ansible.builtin.command: /abc/fold/bin/abh 'ansible'
  environment:
    PATH: "/some_path"
    PYTHONPATH: "/some_other_path/"
```